# Link text larger than parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div, and inside that div is a link

```
<div class="something">
<a href="#">Databases</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I set the width of my div, smaller then the width that the text of the link is. the text of the link just goes outside of the parent div.

What I want is that the text breaks to a new line.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the CSS [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) rule.

```
a {
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/huwfG/)**

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
a{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sa93/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `word-break` property on the anchor `<a>` tag.

```
a{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

As [this documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) explains, this will work since

> *In addition to ‘normal’ soft wrap opportunities, lines may break between any two letters (except where forbidden by the ‘line-break’ property). Hyphenation is not applied.*

This will force the word to split whenever the text reaches the boundary of the container, breaking onto a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to tell the browser to break the word down as it would multiple words:

```
.something{word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.something a {
    /* see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935 for details */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```