# JqGrid : Customize column name display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in the which i display some info..

My column name should appear in the same way as below

```
    Canada          Australia
Month / Year     Month / Year
```

Tha is how i need to display my columns each column name should display Month/Year below it.

as of now my code looks like

```
  colnames: [Id,Canada,Australia,Usa]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depend on what you need exactly. The text from `colNames` items is in general HTML fragment. So you can use `<br/>` for example:

```js
colNames: ["Id", "Canada<br/>Month / Year", "Australia<br/>Month / Year",
           "Usa<br/>Month / Year"]
```

To have the height of the column headers increased you could include CSS like

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div { height: auto }
```

after `ui.jqgrid.css`.

Alternatively you could want that the text in column header will be wrapped. The case are discussed before in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935).