# jqGrid - HeaderText of columns are not displayed properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with fixed width of 445px. In **all Version of IE (v6,v7,v8 and v9)**, HeaderText is not displayed properly. In other browsers it is working well. **Any solution for this issue?**
[image]

Comment: Under IE you mean probably some very old version of IE like IE6?

Comment: Problem with IE 6, 7, 8, 9 in all versions

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to verify that the HTML file starts with `<!DOCTYPE html ...`: (`<!DOCTYPE html>` or `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` depend on the HTML or XHTML dialect which you use). Additionally I recommend you to verify whether the configuration of IE has activate the [compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode). If the compatibility mode are used the problem can be solved by including

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

at the beginning of the `<head>` of the HTML page. I include the above line in all productive pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a Doc type related issue. As I'm working with a component and do not have handle on page doc type so I tried to find a workaround. Now it is working well for me..

```
   // Soon after rendering the jqGrid do the following operation 
   if ($.browser.msie) {
        var mode = Visifire.Validator.msiemode();
        if (mode == 5) {
            // Applying workaround for HeaderText warping issue in IE
            var gridParent = vc_JQ(dataGridSettings.parentId);
            var gridHeader = vc_JQ(".ui-jqgrid-htable", gridParent);
            var headerTextDivs = vc_JQ("div.ui-th-div-ie", gridHeader);
            headerTextDivs.width('90%');
        }
    }
```

Comment: The wrong size of the text is not the only problem which you will have if the page where it will be used have no `<!DOCTYPE`. You can have wrong alignment in different browsers for example, different box model calculation and so on. In the case the web browser will work in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). You will have problems with the usage of jQuery UI too. I recommend you as the component developer don't support including of your component in the paging in  quirks mode like you probably not support working of your component in IE5 or IE4.